# Set dynamic hoverlabel font color based on the background color in plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

Because of an issue in plotly, when you set the hoverlabel border color to transparent, the text gets transparent, too (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3060). You can override the font color of course, but no matter the background of the hoverlabel, the font color stays the same. This can become an issue if you have many different labels in different colors, because some combinations become hard to read.

Plotly itself has a solution by checking the contrast of both colors and setting the text color accordingly, except when you override the text color of course. So my question is:

Can you set the hoverlabel font color dynamically based on the background color in plotly for python?